# parsing xml via python: when I have the same child names

Tags: python

I am stuck in a problem. What I am trying to do is loop over all the nodes and their child elements and get the result for each node element separately.
The XML file content is:

```
<meandata>
<interval begin="0.00" end="60.00" id="edge1"/>
      <edge id="e1"/>
      <edge id="e2"/>
      <edge id="e3"/>
      <edge id="e4"/>
</interval>
<interval begin="60.00" end="120.00" id="edge1"/>
    <edge id="e1"/>
    <edge id="e2"/>
    <edge id="e4"/>
    <edge id="e7"/>
</interval>
```

The code I have written is:

```
data_file = filename.xml
tree = ET.parse(data_file)
root = tree.getroot()
for interval in tree.findall("interval"):
    for i in root.iter('edge'):
        print(i.attrib['id'])
    print("\n")
```

The o/p I desired is:

```
e1
e2
e3
e4

e1
e2
e4
e7 

But, the o/p I am getting is:
e1
e2
e3
e4
e1
e2
e4
e7

e1
e2
e3
e4
e1
e2
e4
e7
```

It's somehow looping over all the child elements for my node. Please help me out.

Comment: Why the nested loops, especially since you ignore `interval`?

Comment: because I want the output segregated in terms of intervals, as you can see there are multiple intervals. let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: Then shouldn't the inner loop refer to `interval`?  Otherwise, the outer loop might as well be `for _ in range(2):`.

Comment: I am pretty new to it. can you please help me out?

Comment: and is there a way to avoid using range(2) because in my original code I have multiple intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate in inner loop not using root, but selected element. This code should work:

```
xml ='''<meandata>
<interval begin="0.00" end="60.00" id="edge1"/>
      <edge id="e1"/>
      <edge id="e2"/>
      <edge id="e3"/>
      <edge id="e4"/>
</interval>
<interval begin="60.00" end="120.00" id="edge1">
    <edge id="e1"/>
    <edge id="e2"/>
    <edge id="e4"/>
    <edge id="e7"/>
</interval></meandata>'''



import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)

for interval in tree.findall("interval"):
    for i in interval.iter('edge'):
        print(i.attrib['id'])
    print("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Some issues

I got this error because malformed XML:

> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 8, column 2

After I removed the slashes from opening tags `<interval .. id="edge1'>` to be valid XML and fit to the closing tags `</interval>`, I got another error:

> ```
> root = tree.getroot()
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'getroot'

I removed the line, because `root` is not needed when `tree.findall()` and nested for-loop uses `interval.iter()` instead:

#### Solution

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """
<meandata>
<interval begin="0.00" end="60.00" id="edge1">
      <edge id="e1"/>
      <edge id="e2"/>
      <edge id="e3"/>
      <edge id="e4"/>
</interval>
<interval begin="60.00" end="120.00" id="edge1">
    <edge id="e1"/>
    <edge id="e2"/>
    <edge id="e4"/>
    <edge id="e7"/>
</interval>
</meandata>
"""
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)

# tree = ET.parse(data_file)
for interval in tree.findall("interval"):
    for edge in interval.iter('edge'):
        print(edge.attrib['id'])
    print("\n")
```

Output:

```
e1
e2
e3
e4


e1
e2
e4
e7
```

Note: For testing purpose I used [`ET.fromstring`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring) with input as [multiline-string](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_multi_line_strings.asp) instead `ET.parse` (see help: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

You should fix your file-name. I am pretty sure you want to put in quotes like `'filename.xml'`.